# WinAPI Tab Bar Rendering

Tags: winapi

I'm writing a C-based WinAPI program that has a tab control in the client area of the main window. This tab control works great, except there appears to be some kind of rendering issue with the tabs. The titles of tabs are rendered in bold, unaliased fonts, and therefore waste a lot of screen real estate:
[image]
Here's what tabs look like in essentially every other application:
[image]

I use this code to set up my tab control:

```
RECT rcClient, rcTool, rcTab;
TCHAR tabTitleTmp[256]; // Temp string buffer

HWND hTool = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_MAIN_TOOL);
GetWindowRect(hTool, &rcTool);
int iToolHeight = rcTool.bottom - rcTool.top;

// Get parent's client rect
GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient); 

// Create tab control
HWND hwndTab = CreateWindowEx(NULL, WC_TABCONTROL, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VISIBLE, 
     0, iToolHeight, rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom - iToolHeight, hWnd, (HMENU) IDC_MAIN_TAB,
     hInst, NULL);

// Create tab items
TCITEM tie; 
tie.mask = TCIF_TEXT | TCIF_IMAGE; 
tie.iImage = -1; 
tie.pszText = tabTitleTmp; 

// Set up tabs
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    LoadString(hInst, IDC_TAB_GENERAL + i, tabTitleTmp, sizeof(tabTitleTmp) / sizeof(tabTitleTmp[0]));
    TabCtrl_InsertItem(hwndTab, i, &tie);
}
```

Does anyone know the solution to this problem? I haven't yet found it on Google, and I'm beginning to think this might just be a bug in WinAPI itself. Thanks for any responses!

**Edit:** I call InitCommonControlsEx() at the beginning of my program before creating any controls, so the common control classes are registered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the font on the tab control using [`SendMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the [`WM_SETFONT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632642%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message. <del>You can use [`GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144925%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the default GUI font,</del> You can use [`SystemParametersInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms724947%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get the default font, or you can set a different font using [`CreateFont()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
NONCLIENTMETRICS ncm;
ncm.cbSize = sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS);
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS), &ncm, NULL);
HFONT hFont = CreateFontIndirect(&ncm.lfMessageFont);
SendMessage(hwndTab, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, true);
```

Comment: Yep, that does it! Out of curiosity, was this just something you discovered yourself, or was it buried deep in some M$ docs?

Comment: @TristanSeifert, something I discovered a long time ago. I immediately knew what the problem was when I saw your screenshot. In my old projects, I was using `GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT)`. After I posted the answer I went back and was reading the MSDN articles, and it said `SystemParametersInfo` is the preferred way, hence the edit.

Comment: @TristanSeifert, this is actually something you normally see with most all controls, especially static labels which you seem to be using. I'm surprised you aren't seeing this issue on your other controls as well.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Thanks for that piece of knowledge... I'm relatively new to doing WinAPI work, so I'll keep this in mind in the future. A lot of the tutorials on the Internet seem to omit this step which is probably why I don't know about it. You'd expect WinAPI to do this for you, but meh.